# Entity Framework Code First - Create new base

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I've been working with EF a couple weeks now. I have about 25 migrations that I've created by using Add-Migration, I am synced up with all my environments (dev -> prod). I'd like to set this current state as a new baseline, is that possible? So this way I will have 1 initial migration to work with. I am not sure if EF tools has an easy way to do this, my other option was to delete all migration scripts in the folder, and delete all migration history in the table _MigrationHistory

Comment: You can call a specific migration by calling the name of the migration. Let's say you have called "TestMigration" you will need to run: update-database -TargetMigration TestMigration

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this.

**Step 1 :** Delete all the migration scripts on the `Migrations` folder.

**Step 2 :** Delete all the records on the `__MigrationHistory` table on the database.

**Step 3 :** `PM> Add-Migration "My-First-Migration"`

**Step 4 :** `PM> Update-Database`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this.

**Step 1** : Delete all the migration scripts on the Migrations folder.

**Step 2** : Delete all the records on the __MigrationHistory table on the database.

**Step 3** :  Delete Database

**Step 4** : PM> Add-Migration "$InitialDatabase"

now you update any thing in entity then not need to make new Migration 
just update existing migration using below command.

**Step 5** : PM> Update-Database -TargetMigration $InitialDatabase -Verbose

**Step 6** : PM> Update-Database -Verbose